# I'm receiving a syntax error which I can't understand in form

Tags: php, html

I've written code so I can create a form, but there is an error which I can't understand.

**My Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<?php
include("menu_admin.php");
?>
<div style="clear:both">
<form action="edit.php" method="post" style="margin-left:502px">

<table >
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name"  /></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>Age</td>
<td><input type="text" name="age"  /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Phone No</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phonenum"  /></td>
</tr>
<!--value="  echo $phonenum; " size="30"-->

<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="date"  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>E-mail</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"  /></td>
</tr>





<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  /></td>
</tr>


</table>

</form>

</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\SRK\admin\manage.php on line 103
```

The line which the compiler pointing is the last line, where I end my program with the `</html>` tag.

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: Have you ever considered you error can be in `menu_admin.php` ?

Comment: there is an unclosed `{` in `menu_admin.php`

Comment: @CodeBird how come you know the error is `an unclosed {` without looking at the code in the file  `menu_admin.php`?

Comment: @sandip - Because it's the most obvious way to get that parse error.

Comment: menu_admin.php is the menu file where i use to put my menu, there is no any baraket use and no close braket

Comment: Update your question with the contents of `menu_admin.php` removing any sensitive information such as password and usernames. [You can edit your question to include more information by clicking here or on the Edit link below your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23058827/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a PHP error, the only PHP in that code you've provided is the include.

You will find that in `menu_admin.php` there is a closing brace missing. If you lint check `menu_admin.php` It should help you locate the error better. But it will be an unclosed `{` somewhere.

Comment: **menu_admin.php**
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
<div style="margin-left:260px;">
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="manage.php">Manage</a></li>
 <li><a href="dash.php">Edit Paragraph</a>
  
 </li>
 <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: ok ok i solve the problem